# Quicksand Font Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, quicksand

I'm using Quicksand from google webfonts on a site I'm developing, but some weird stuff happens when I access the page from Windows browsers.

For instance, the word "STOREFRONTS" comes out like this:

[image: storefronts]

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: I have the same issue, found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in two environments, for example a Mac side and a Windows side, and the discrepancy appears in the Windows side only in whichever browser you try that supports Web Fonts (IE 6+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4.2+, etc. https://developers.google.com/webfonts/faq), it may be that you have a system-level typeface installed with the same name as Quicksand and that it's using that typeface instead. You might also try here, specifically about the CORS issue in newer versions of Firefox and IE 9+ (https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/troubleshooting). An example page or code for how you're loading the typeface in might be helpful, too.